# WPF ValueConverter Long to String implementation error

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am new to WPF and am trying to implement an IValueConverter to convert a Long value to a String so I can then format it to HH:mm in a DataGrid, but I'm having issue implementing the ValueConverter it is throwing the following error:

**Error:**

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'IGPC2UI.LongConverter' to type 'System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter'.

**ValueConverter (LongConverter.cs)**

```
public class LongConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string valueConvert = value.ToString();
            return valueConvert;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="IGPC2UI.Views.OrdersView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IGPC2UI"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Background="White"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:LongConverter x:Key="LongConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="Orders" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
                  ColumnWidth="*" CanUserReorderColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>                
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="PFT"/>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PFT, Converter={StaticResource LongConverter}}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>                    
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Am I implementing this correctly? The original binding (long) value displays if I don't use the Converter.

Comment: The code looks ok. Where exactly does the exception occur? Does it disappear when you write `public class LongConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter`?

Comment: often, when i see that exception, there are more types with the same name in different namespaces, if that's the case @Clemens example should "fix" the problem, since it includes the namespace

Comment: Ah yes @Clemens suggestion did indeed fix the issue, thanks.

Comment: Then you somehow managed to have a different IValueConverter interface declaration in your project. Remove that.